# Is it possible to nominate someone else as a mod?

Tags: discussion, election

I only see an option to nominate myself as a moderator. What if I want to nominate someone else?

Comment: I haven't checked yet, but I'm guessing this (and a bunch of other q's people will have) are direct dupes to MSO.

Comment: I had the same question.  If someone finds the answer, it might be worth linking from the election announcement.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, the announcement links to [meta-tag:election].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[As quoted on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75383/179):

> All nominations are by definition self-nominations. Nominating others is absolutely not supported.

[Jeff Atwood's explanation](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1305) starts with:

> When we did allow outside nominations, it caused a lot of problems:
>
> - users often did not know they were nominated by someone else
> - users sometimes did not want to be nominated at all
> - it implies a lot of coordination, more than there actually is, between users

Comment: That's interesting.  UX had moderator elections a few months ago (more recently than that post) and most candidates were nominated by others, not themselves.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, are you sure? All of the [nominations](http://ux.stackexchange.com/election/1) look self-recommending to me.

Comment: That's my memory, but I just tried to go to the election page to confirm and I don't see nominations (presumably because the election has finished).  Where are you looking?  Perhaps what I'm remembering was a discussion elsewhere before the formal elections?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Oops. My link didn't go straight to the nomination tab. Try this one: http://ux.stackexchange.com/election/1?tab=nomination

Comment: Apparently I misremembered, or I'm thinking of something informal like a (no-longer-present) brainstorming meta post or chat or something.  Thanks for the link.